# program's printf backslash n does not carriage return when compiled with Eclipse

Tags: printf, eclipse-cdt

I handed in a C program which contained a lot of verbose printf debug lines. I always compiled it command line with gcc.

Now it's been turned into an Eclipse-CDT (Helios) project, and my

```
\n
```

no longer do carriage returns. I get an unreadable "staircase" in my console.

RCINAHFM. Is there a check box in the IDE I need to modify or do I need to go back and carefully modify hundreds of lines of code?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Bert

RCINAHFM=Remaining calm / I need a hug from Mom

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse does not compile C all by itself. It uses an external compiler for that, usually gcc. So it’s highly unlikely that the compiled program is incorrect, unless the compiler configuration within Eclipse does something very, very weird.

If you get a “staircase”, it sounds as if the *new line* part is carried out, but no *carriage return* happens. This might happen under systems that use CR/LF as their line ending, such as DOS/Windows.

Unfortunately, you give way to little detail. Are you using Unix or Windows? Where does the program run, in an XTerm, a Windows DOS console, within the Eclipse console? If the answer is “Eclipse console”, then have you tried running it in another terminal instead; or tried running your original program in the Eclipse console? Are you using `printf` or some other function?